# Copy HTML w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table and a link below it. I need to be able to click that link, copy the table above, with all its contents and paste it below that original table.

```
<table>
...
</table>
<br>

<a href="#" id="copyTbl">copy</a>
```

I tried something like this, but failed:

```
$("#copyTbl").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("table").html().clone().appendTo("br");
});
```

Am I stringing it improperly?

Comment: Are you intending to insertAfter the br tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, short and simple:

http://jsfiddle.net/wfqa7/6/

edit: be careful when cloning elements with IDs :P

edit: handle IDs when cloning http://jsfiddle.net/wfqa7/8/

Comment: Will it clone ID too? I suppose clone is clone, hah?

Comment: yes, it clones the entire DOM element, ID and all... may be better to select on a class instead since having multiple elements with the same class does not violate any standards :P

Comment: Can ID be re-written after clone()? id="myTable" -> id="myTable1"

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues there.  `closest` looks for the first matching ancestor.  Since the link is not contained within the table, that will not match.  You will need to match it different, maybe an `id` or some other selector based on your full html structure.

2nd, you cannot append to a `br` since `appendTo` places the element inside and `br` has no "inside".  You want to use `insertAfter` instead.

EDIT: and as pointed out by SLaks, drop the `html` and clone the table, you can't clone the string.

Comment: OK, assuming I don't know the ID and I already added a bunch of tables, how to I clone the last one, the one "closest" to the link?

Comment: If these are the only tables on the page you could use `$("table").last()`, hard to say exactly without knowing the whole page.

Comment: Getting warmer! :) All that code is within a larger table (table layout...), so I guess it won't work. Really closest would've been the best... :(

Answer (score 3):

`.html()` returns a string.
You can't clone a string.

You should either call `.clone()` to return new DOM nodes or `.html()` to return a raw HTML string, but not both.

Also, you can't put a table inside a `<br />`; you should call `insertAfter`; not `appendTo`.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I stringing it improperly?

Yes and no. `.html()` returns a string, which does not have a `.clone()` method.<sup>1</sup> Either clone the elements, *or* use `.html()`:

```
$("#copyTbl").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("table").clone().insertAfter("br");
    // or
    $("br").after($(this).closest("table").html());
});
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Strings are immutable, so there's no need for a clone method.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Closest would mean the link is inside the table.
Many ways to do this:
http://jsbin.com/aqamok